# how to plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made data.frame:

```
> dfm
  iteration   fcm    gk    gg
1         1 28.15 28.15 28.15
2         2 16.25 15.82 15.99
3         3 15.05 14.55 14.02
4         4 11.61 11.00 11.12
```

Next step is to melt this:

```
dfm <- melt(df, id.vars=c("iteration","fcm","gk","gg"))
```

Now,I have problems with aes of the ggplot.My goal is to create one plot,three columns to be represented with different colours.

Comment: A very good starting point is Hadley's book: [ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis](https://www.google.de/search?q=ggplot2%3A%20Elegant%20Graphics%20for%20Data%20Analysis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use all variables as `id.vars` try this code

```
dfm <- melt(df, id.vars=c("iteration"))
```

What do you really need to plot?? What is your x and y axis? line plot or point? As far as i
understood this should work.

```
ggplot(dfm,aes(iterartion,value,colour=variable))+geom_point()
```